# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device - AWS Lambda + Zappa

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, zappa

I have deployed an application on AWS lambda using Zappa. I get the error in zappa tail - OSError: No space left on device.
The file size is large so I am using S3 as well. Below is my zappa settings.

```
{"dev": {
"app_function": "app.app",
"profile_name": "default",
"aws_region": "------",
"project_name": "----",
"runtime": "python3.6",
"s3_bucket": "------",
"timeout_seconds": 300,
"slim_handler": true
}
}
```

below is the stack trace:

```
[Errno 28] No space left on device: OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 609, in lambda_handler
  return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
  handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 97, in __init__
  self.load_remote_project_archive(project_archive_path)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 169, in load_remote_project_archive
  t.extractall(project_folder)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2012, in extractall
  numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2054, in extract
  numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2124, in _extract_member
  self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2173, in makefile
  copyfileobj(source, target, tarinfo.size, ReadError, bufsize)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 252, in copyfileobj
  dst.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Lambda doesn't appear to be the correct solution for you.  Have you looked at your own EC2 or other AWS technologies?

Comment: Not yet, but need to know why this issue is occurring and how can I deal with it? I am using S3 to handle the space issue.

Comment: It looks like you're loading something remotely and trying to untar it (a guess as there is no code).  Are you now trying to stream to S3?  We're just guessing without some code.

Comment: it uploads zipped version of the code to s3 and then unzip it. There is code for sure.

Comment: The unzipped version of the code must be less than 250MB.  How big is your code deployment package unzipped?

Comment: zipped version is 160 mb, unzipped around 700

Comment: why it has to be less than 250 since I am using s3 for that purpose?

Comment: That's nearly 3X the amount that [Lambda limits you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).  You can't just create a deployment of any size and expect Lambda to run it.

Comment: I know that is why we use S3 right?

Comment: most of the code is in S3, lamda space is not much used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a memory issue.
Cleaning up the code and the virtualenv solved the problem.
Removed extra libraries which were not required to reduce the space.